# onCreate и onPostExecute()

Tags: java, android, сервер

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    ArrayList<String> books=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,books);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //books.add("NEW NEW NEW"); ЭТО РАБОТАЕТ
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}

class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String a, b, answerHTTP;
    String server = "blabla.net";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget;
        try {
            httpget = new HttpGet(server + "?req=getList");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                answerHTTP = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(answerHTTP);
            JSONArray jsonNames=jo.getJSONArray("names");
            JSONArray jsonAuthors=jo.getJSONArray("authors");

            //editText.setText(jsonNames.getString(0));



            for(int i=0;i<jsonNames.length();i++){
                books.add("New man"); // ЭТО НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }
}
```

}

При обращении к books из OnPostExecute выдаёт исключение. А при обращении к books из OnCreate всё правильно отрабатывает.

Comment: Нужно чтобы работало из OnPostExecute

Comment: У вас вообще решение само по себе плохое. Обращаться к глобальной переменной `Activity` из `AsyncTask` - плохо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявили books в `onCreate()`, его поле видимости остается там же.
Объявите его в теле класса, а инициализируйте в `onCreate()`, `books` станет видимым для всех методов:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> books;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        books=new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```